# Not understanding Array range reference

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm not understanding why `Sub join_example()` works but `Sub join_2_example()` doesn't work.

[image: Code Image]

Comment: You should explain HOW it doesn't work and what the expected result is when it does work.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you have a read of these links please:  [ask] and [mcve].  Also could you paste the actual code so it can be copied rather than a picture of the code

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm learning VBA and am new to all of this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code creates and uses a **one-dimensional** array.
The second code creates a **two-dimensional** array.

That is why `Join()` fails in the second case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use application.transpose once to convert a 2-D array of the values from multiple rows in a single column or use it twice to convert the values from multiple columns in a single row.

```
Dim na As Variant, fn As String

na = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("b1:f1").Value2))
fn = Join(na, "-")

Debug.Print fn
```

p.s. It's always a pleasure to have to retype code that should have been copied from the VBE and pasted into a code block.

Comment: Thanks for your help.